# Telerik - RadGrid - Group by formatting

Tags: formatting, telerik, grouping

I was able to get the grouping to work but I need to format the date.

```
GridGroupByField groupBy = new GridGroupByField();
groupBy.FormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy"; this just displays what is in the string
```

This is what is displaying in the group header.  If I remove the formatting it uses the time and I only need the date.

"By Date / Rev Code: MM/dd/yyyy"

This is w/o formatting:
"By Date / Rev Code: 12/14/2020 12:00:00 AM"

Thanks in advance.
Mark

Comment: do i need to give more info? thought that might be enough for what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with this component, but based on this site https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/grouping/group-by-expressions/programmatic-definition you could formatting it like this:

```
GridGroupByField groupBy = new GridGroupByField();
groupBy.FormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}";
```

Comment: Ugg not sure why I didn't think of that.  Thanks

Comment: Happy I could help you. Please accept the answer for future viewers.